# How relevant was Wernher von Braun really?

Tags: history, space-race, wernher-von-braun

Wernehr von Braun is named "Father of the moon landing" and deemed very important to the success of the space race back in the day. But was he really? What were his personal contributions?
He brought a team of 120 people from Peenemünde with him. What about the contributions of those?
Also it seems that his connections with Nazi ideology is played down. Could it be that the public record paints an image that is too positive of someone who was just lucky and stratetic to be in the right position at the right time?

The question also arises, because basically everyone had an interest in keeping the the idea of "a rocket enthusiast who was a genius but did not care about politics" alive. The germans had someone to point to and say:"it would not have been possible without 'us'". And the US would have an interest in not disclosing that they had saved a raging nazi from prosecution only to find out that they had been duped by him about his own brilliance.

Comment: The second part feels like a separate (and probably less-on-topic) question. It might or might not fit in History, HSM or even politics SE depending on how it’s written.

Comment: @uhoh that's true. But can it really be separated? There is so much that played into this. Politics, history, personal stuff... Maybe the whole question would belong to history? (I've just aded another part after your comment, sorry)

Comment: Let's see what happens!

Comment: I'm voting to close this as opinion based. The fact he was relevant is not in doubt, there's no way to give a measurable or fact-based answer as to how much.

Comment: This is a classic example of a question that would take a book to answer. As you say "there is so much that played into this".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Management skills (the ability to herd cats) and technical skills (the ability to hunt like a cat) are very distinct skillsets. People who have both skillsets are rare. A wide range of technical skills are needed for "rocket science" (it's really "rocket engineering", but everyone calls it "rocket science".) Pursuing too many technical skills typically makes one be a jack of all trades, master of none. People who are a jack of all trades, master of many, and also are highly competent managers are extremely rare.

Once someone reaches a high enough level of management it is the decision making skills that predominate over technical skills, and that can sometimes lead to bad decisions. Most people climb managerially or technically until they reach a level of relative incompetence. This is the [Peter Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_principle). People who can continue to make decisions that are good from both a management and technical perspective as they climb higher managerially are beyond extremely rare.

Wernher von Braun was beyond extremely rare.

Comment: @OrganicMarble right, it was not well phrased (it was not, what I wanted to imply!).. I've therefore deleted my comment.

Comment: Von Braun's work on the V-2 also made him an engineer of war. How much he was involved in versus knew about versus how much he intentionally ignored regarding the horrors of Nazi Germany has long been in question. I didn't want to address that because that would take a book. Many books have been written about him, some of which took a dim view of him. My answer focuses on the question in the title of the OP. Even von Braun's detractors give him that much. The only possible comparison is with [Sergei Korolev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sergei_Korolev).